# LineChart values are automatically rounded

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I tried it already at the primefaces forum without success, so I will post my problem also here.

I'm trying to use a line chart with floating point values. Here is my code:

```
<p:lineChart value="#{bean.linearModel}"  minY="0.0" maxY="20.0" xaxisAngle="-90" legendPosition="e"/>
```

The values from the linearModel are BigDecimal (y axis) between 15.0 and 18.0 and Strings (x axis). The BigDecimal values are automatically rounded to integer values. 
When I set the maxY value to "20.1" then it works great and the bigdecimal values are correctly shown. but then the grid looks very strange.

I'm using PF 3.3. I tried it also with double values instead of BigDecimal, but same problem.

Thanks for help!

Comment: how about casting them into strings ? (the BigDecimals of y axis)